# Working with MySQL Vertical Designed table

Tags: database

I have an html form (each form has different page, according to date), with five text inputs, called date, inp1, inp2, inp3 and inp4.

For example, I have database table, with structure like this: `id | parent | name | value`.
In this case, I want to store my data, and adding it to date by parent, like this:

```
id | parent | name | value
1  | 0      | date | 20.07.2011
2  | 1      | inp1 | value-from-inp1
3  | 1      | inp2 | value-from-inp2
4  | 0      | date | 21.07.2011
5  | 4      | inp2 | value-from-inp2
6  | 1      | inp3 | value-from-inp3
7  | 4      | inp1 | value-from-inp1
```

and so on...

But problem starts here. I want to create option, that you can update those values for previously added. 
But the QUESTIONS are, how to check, if

1. Do I have anything assigned to that date already?
  1. If is assigned, how to determine, and use MySQL Update for that
  2. If is not assigned, how to determine, and use MySQL Insert Into for that

My stupid and 50% more inefficient of loading page solution for this problem sounds like this (Don't worry about security, its just mock-up):

```
if($_POST['submit']){
$inp1_data = $db->get_row("SELECT name FROM table WHERE parent = ".$parent_id." and name='inp1'");
if($inp1_data){$db->update($query)}else{$db->insert($query)}

// ... and so on, four copies of same code, just replacing "inp1" to "inp2", "inp3"...
}
```

Yes, I know, this is useless script, in case, if I have added one more, or hundreds of inpNUMBER, it would be crush test site, 100% guaranteed timeout, not working script.

Comment: I suggest you normalize your database. Having the type of one column (`value`) depend on another (`name`) is not good.

Comment: I know, maybe this type of database is not right for this time, but I show myself in near future, that I need to use this type. For example,  user created forms, and different names, and it would be impossible with horizontal type of database.

Comment: I understand what your name and value columns represent after your comment, but what is parent?

Comment: Parent is that, which links up with id column, and gets date, and other stuff, if needed (not in this case)

Comment: So, are you saying in this example that there's a form that's been submitted on 20.07.2011 with values inp1 = value-from-inp1 and inp2 = value-from-inp2?

Comment: Yes, kind of, but after your question, I realized that parent column is not needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to use a singe table where you really need two.  To answer your question, because the date is stored separately from the value, there is no way to find out if you have a value assigned to a particular question using a single `SELECT`.  You may be able to do this with a nested select, but I won't try to go through the contortions to make it happen.

Consider this alternative design, which assumes that a given field can't be repeated for a given submission:

Submission table

```
submission_id | date
1             | 20.07.2011
2             | 21.07.2011
```

answers table

```
submission_id | field_name | field_value
1             | inp1       | value-from-inp1
1             | inp2       | value-from-inp2
2             | inp2       | value-from-inp2
2             | inp4       | value-from-inp4
1             | inp3       | value-from-inp3
```

Note that Randolf Rincón-Fadul's suggestion of keeping the data types separated by field is a good one, but I haven't done it here to keep things simple.  Now you can find out if you have an answer for a particular date by joining the tables.

Comment: Okey, now I got it :) Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

RobertR I agree with Kerrek this is a VERY BAD idea man! You should normalize your data. This structure doesn't provide any of the real DB advantages and trying to parse and maintain data based on your "schema" will be painful.

Theres is always a form. If you need to maintain user defined data then use generic db columns like [FIELD_NAME][FIELD_TEXT_VALUE] and  [FIELD_NAME][FIELD_DATE_VALUE] where all are atomic.

Comment: Actually this is a way "Tags" could be implemented. +1 for simplicity.

Comment: Well, okey, probably I should to normalize it to horizontal. But in case, next project in my head is something, which totally couldn't work without vertical design. So, I'm just looking forward, starting with this example :)