# Database design for multi-level user type and profiles

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am developing a school management system with multiple user types/levels; teachers, students, parents etc.

They all have common data such as name, email, telephone, gender etc. Each user type has its own table (`tbl_students`, `tbl_teachers` etc) for other data that is not common.

Should I include these fields in the `tbl_users` table which will be used to handle the login and subsequent redirection to a relevant part of the site (based on user type), OR have a very minimal `tbl_users` table with only user id and password?

If the `tbl_users` is minimal, would it be ok when it comes to performance to have two MySQL statements to insert data into two tables on new user registration?

This is my main doubt/question:

Would it be a drain on MySQL performance to constantly have to do joins when displaying simple things like user profiles, contact details etc if the common data is stored in the `tbl_users` field itself? Or would it be worse in performance if all the basic data is in the other tables such as `tbl_teachers` would have `firstnames`, `telephone` etc?

Comment: Why you don't build ONE table for ALL users and simply make a attribut like "role" and then you save integers in there.. from 0 to X. Then you simply define in your code 0 = teacher, 1 = student etc.

Comment: because not all the data is the same for teachers, students, parents etc.

Comment: As per my understanding `tbl_users` use for common fields, login credentials and type. And create sub table for another details. Refer [Vertical Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811218/working-with-mysql-vertical-designed-table).

Comment: You question may have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types/13752304#13752304

Comment: @WalterMitty Thanks! That did in fact answer my question :)